# Looping over nodes and extracting specific subnode values using Java's XPath

Tags: java, xpath

I understand from Googling that it makes more sense to extract data from XML using XPath than by using DOM looping.

At the moment, I have implemented a solution using DOM, but the code is verbose, and it feels untidy and unmaintainable, so I would like to switch to a cleaner XPath solution.

Let's say I have this structure:

```xml
<products>
    <product>
        <title>Some title 1</title>
        <image>Some image 1</image>
    </product>
    <product>
        <title>Some title 2</title>
        <image>Some image 2</image>
    </product>
    ...
</products>
```

I want to be able to run a for loop for each of the `<product>` elements, and inside this for loop, extract the title and image node values.

My code looks like this:

```
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();          
DocumentBuilder builder =
  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(is);
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/products/product");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList products = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < products.getLength(); i++) {
    Node n = products.item(i);
    if (n != null && n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element product = (Element) n;
        // do some DOM navigation to get the title and image
    }
}
```

Inside my `for` loop I get each `<product>` as a `Node`, which is cast to an `Element`.

Can I simply use my instance of `XPathExpression` to compile and run another `XPath` on the `Node` or the `Element`?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can always do like this  -

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/products/product");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
expr = xpath.compile("title"); // The new xpath expression to find 'title' within 'product'.

NodeList products = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < products.getLength(); i++) {
    Node n = products.item(i);
    if (n != null && n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element product = (Element) n;
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList)  expr.evaluate(product,XPathConstants.NODESET); //Find the 'title' in the 'product'
        System.out.println("TITLE: " + nodes.item(0).getTextContent()); // And here is the title 
    }
}
```

Here I have given example of extracting the 'title' value. In same way you can do for 'image'

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a big fan of this approach because you have to build a document (which might be expensive) before you can apply XPaths to it.

I've found [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) a lot more efficient when it comes to applying XPaths to documents, because you don't need to load the whole document into memory. Here is some sample code:

```
final VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
vg.parseFile("file.xml", false);
final VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
final AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);

ap.selectXPath("/products/product");
while (ap.evalXPath() != -1) {
    System.out.println("PRODUCT:");

    // you could either apply another xpath or simply get the first child
    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "title")) {
        int val = vn.getText();
        if (val != -1) {
            System.out.println("Title: " + vn.toNormalizedString(val));
        }
        vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
    }
    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "image")) {
        int val = vn.getText();
        if (val != -1) {
            System.out.println("Image: " + vn.toNormalizedString(val));
        }
        vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
    }
}
```

Also see this post on [Faster XPaths with VTD-XML](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2010/08/faster-xpaths-with-vtd-xml.html).